# How can I add native ads to my React Native app?

Tags: react-native, admob, ads, facebook-audience-network

Google Admob: https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob
Doesn't support native ads

Facebook Audience Network: https://github.com/callstack/react-native-fbads
Significant hit on performance (~10 UI FPS per native ad rendered)

It's really demotivating to try all these libraries only to see they fail at some point. How can I putt multiple native ads in a React Native app?

Comment: Have you tried looking at this: https://dev-yakuza.github.io/en/react-native/react-native-admob/ It gets Admob working in native.